# IE6 and SP2010 functionality

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

If I run SP 2010 UI in MOSS 2007 compatibility mode by using UIVersion=3 do I still get all of the SP 2010 functionality eg enterprises wide taxonomy and metadata and FAST for SP 2010 and document and records management functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

IE6 is not supported as an authoring browser in SP2010.

Read more on the support levels for browsers on TechNet

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(office.14).aspx

Just saw Randy Drisgill did a nice post on this subject as well: http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-5-handling.html

Comment: Hi Anders

Totally agree if you are using the SP 2010 UI (UIVersion=4) but as the UI is still MOSS 2007 UIVersion=3) and looks and feels like MOSS 2007 why should IE6 not be supported ?

Regards

Nigel

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure, i think the version only changes the general navigation and editing like the ribbon, while the HTML editor for example is the same across versions (i will check this when i get access to a box tomorrow). Hence support for level 3 browsers should not be expected.